# Get different results when loop using more than one value

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I'm trying to write a light curve simulation for transit, however, when use more than one value for the inclination ('ibound' in the code below), there will be some weird horizontal line in the final figure, but it will not happen if only one value is used each time, e.g.ibound=[80,82] is not ok, but ibound=[80] or ibound=[82] gives the correct result.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r_p=1.314*(7.149e7)                 
r_s=0.826*(6.957e8)                 
Area_p=np.pi*r_p**2.
P=1.3*86400.
omega=2.*np.pi/P
a=0.0226*(1.496e11)


def r_cen(t):
  return a*np.sqrt( (np.sin(omega*t)**2) + (
      (np.cos(math.radians(i))**2) *
      (np.cos(omega*t)**2) ) )

def A_case2(rcen):
  Aobs = 0.
  nstep = 200
  for step in range(0,nstep):
    r=rcen-r_p+(float(step)*2.*r_p/float(nstep))
    if r>r_s:
      break
    else:
      theta = ((r**2.)+(rcen**2.)-(r_p**2.)) / (2.*r*rcen)
      if theta > 1.:
          theta = 1.
      Aobs=Aobs+(2.*r*np.arccos(theta)*(r_p*2./float(nstep)))
  return Aobs

LC=[]
phase = []
time = []
A=[]
ibound=[80,82]
for i in ibound:
  for t in range(-int(P/5),int(P/5)):
    rcen=r_cen(float(t))
    phase.append(float(t)/P)
    time.append(float(t))
    if rcen>r_s+r_p:
        A = 0.
    elif r_s>rcen+r_p:
        A = Area_p
    else:
        A = A_case2(rcen)
    LC.append(1.-(A/(np.pi*r_s**2)))
    

yaxis = LC
xaxis = phase
plt.plot(xaxis,yaxis,'r',linewidth=1)
plt.xlim([-0.1,0.1])
plt.xlabel('phase')
plt.ylabel('normalised counts')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python`

```
ibound=[80,82,85]  # the size of the list is not important
for i in ibound:
    LC=[]
    phase = []
    time = []
    A=[]
    for t in range(-int(P/5),int(P/5)):
        rcen=r_cen(float(t))
        phase.append(float(t)/P)
        time.append(float(t))
        if rcen>r_s+r_p:
            A = 0.
        elif r_s>rcen+r_p:
            A = Area_p
        else:
            A = A_case2(rcen)
        LC.append(1.-(A/(np.pi*r_s**2)))
        
    yaxis = LC
    xaxis = phase
    plt.plot(xaxis, yaxis, 'r', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.xlim([-0.1, 0.1])
    plt.xlabel('phase')
    plt.ylabel('normalised counts')
plt.show()
```

if you change your block on this, will be what you wanted.
why it combines all the lines already described

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeyII.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Its an artifact of the `plt.plot()` function. As you have put all the results into the same list the plotter will attempt to connect all the data points with a single continuous line. So the end data point of the first pass will get joined to the first point of the second pass.

You can see this clearly if you change the plot parameters,

`plt.plot(xaxis, yaxis, 'or', linewidth=1)`

Which gives,

[image]

As you can see there has been no attempt by the plotter to connect the data points with a continuous line & hence no additional horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `xaxis` values have a single discontinuity halfway through, so `xaxis` looks something like (assuming a step size of 0.1) `[-0.2, -0.1...0.1, 0.2, -0.2, -0.1...0.1, 0.2]`. Like DrBwts said, this is where `plt.plot` connect the points across the discontinuity, resulting in a horizontal line.

If you want the plotter to still connect data points (which is helpful if you want the graph to not look too choppy once you reduce the linewidth), you can replace the last section in your code (from `yaxis = LC` onwards) as follows:

```
yaxis = LC
xaxis = phase

num_elements_per_list = len(phase)//2

x1 = xaxis[:num_elements_per_list]
x2 = xaxis[num_elements_per_list:]

y1 = yaxis[:num_elements_per_list]
y2 = yaxis[num_elements_per_list:]

plt.plot(x1, y1, 'r', linewidth=1)
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'r', linewidth=1)
plt.xlim([-0.1,0.1])

# This line is just to make the x axis a bit prettier
plt.xticks(np.arange(-0.1, 0.101, 0.05))

plt.xlabel('Phase')
plt.ylabel('Normalised Counts')

plt.show()
```

This generates the following plot:

[image: Plot]